# Ways for checking the correctness of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I check the correctness of the solution of the DE?

say the question is,

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-8x+3y-31}{-3x+y-11}$$

I solve it using the method of exact DE, and my solution is,

$$4x^2- 3xy+31x+\frac{y^{2}}{2}-11y=c, c\in \mathbb{R}$$

and the other example,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{9}{2}xe^{\frac{-2y}{x}}+\frac{9}{2}xe^{\frac{2y}{x}}$$
and the potential solution is,
$$y = \frac{-x}{2}\ln|\tan(9x+c)|$$

How can I check the answer like this question?

Comment: Substitute it into both sides of the equation and check

Comment: it is difficult especially for the second question. I have no idea how to convert branch of ln, tan to exponential.

Comment: If you substitute it in the second equation, you'll find that the $\ln$ ends up cancelling the exponentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{9}{2}xe^{\frac{-2y}{x}}+\frac{9}{2}xe^{\frac{2y}{x}}$$
$$\left ( \dfrac yx \right)'=\frac{9}{2}e^{\frac{-2y}{x}}+\frac{9}{2}e^{\frac{2y}{x}}$$
$$w'=9(e^w+e^{-w})$$
Where $w=2\dfrac yx$
$$\int \dfrac {de^w}{e^{2w}+1}=9x+C$$
$$\arctan e^w=9x+C$$
$$w=\ln  |\tan (9x+C)|$$
$$y=\dfrac x2 \ln  |\tan (9x+C)|$$
looks like you made a sign mistake. If you need to check your answer just differentiate $y$.
$$y'= \frac{1}{2}\ln|\tan(9x+c)+ \frac{x}{2}\dfrac {\tan (9x+C)'}{\tan(9x+c)}$$
$$y'= \frac{y}{x}+ \frac{x}{2}\dfrac {\tan (9x+C)'}{\tan(9x+c)}$$
Note that:
$$\tan (9x+C)=e^{2y/x}$$

---

For the first differential equation:
$$4x^2- 3xy+31x+\frac{y^{2}}{2}-11y=c, c\in \mathbb{R}$$
Differentiate:
$$8x- 3y-3xy'+31+yy'-11y'=0$$
$$y'(-3x+y-11)=-8x+3y-31$$
$$y'=\dfrac {-8x+3y-31} {-3x+y-11}$$

Comment: I’m confused. Are you done editing?

Comment: I really make a little mistake, which is in tan(9x+c), it should be tan(-9x+c) since I am letting w = e^-2v in the integral.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes this looks more correct @eulerisgod

Comment: How about the first question? I need to treat it as implicit differentiation in order to obtain dy/dx?

Comment: Yes differentiate implicitely it will works fine the constant will disappear; @eulerisgod

Comment: Super thanks!! :)

Comment: You're very welcome @eulerisgod.